# how to take array of inputs separated by comma in input tag in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to take multiple input separated by comma from user using one input field.
I used `onChange` function to store the user input in a state variable. It is storing each letter in each array index.
For example, If I enter **Red,Blue** as input, it is storing like

```
Array[0]= R
Array[1]= e
Array[2]= d
Array[3]= ,
Array[4]= B
Array[5]= l
Array[6]= u
Array[7]= e
```

I want to store them like

```
 Array[0]= Red
 Array[1]= Blue
```

This is what my `onChange` handler look like:

```
changeHandler=(event)=> {
  this.setState({ 
    [event.target.name]:event.target.value
  })
}
```

How can I do that?
I'm new to react js, any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Post the `onChange` function code

Comment: changeHandler=(event)=>{   
        this.setState({
          [event.target.name]:event.target.value
        })    
    }

Comment: Sounds like you're doing a `.split('')` instead of a `.split(',')`.

Comment: i'm using `.split(',')` now, its working. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Split your input values using comma delimiter:

```
this.setState({
    [e.target.name]:e.target.value.split(',')
  });
```

However, if you are using form its better to use onSubmit event to do these kind of operations. On 'onChange' just collect your input. Just a suggestion though.